# Should I use ondeactivate or onblur when leaving a input textbox?

Tags: javascript, html, input

I have some HTML inputs and I need to run some javascript when the user exits them however I have always used onblur but a colleague has suggested ondeactivate.

I can't find much info about ondeactivate and thought it was an old method for old browsers. Will onblur run on older browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an Internet Explorer-only event - I don't think any other browser has ever implemented it, although I may be wrong.

FWIW, in twelve years of web development involving JavaScript on a daily basis I have never ever used this event.